# specialized std::default_delete with QQmlComponent

Tags: c++, qt, std

I'm trying to 'specialize' the std::default_delete for QQmlComponent without success,my implementation is never called, only the default deleter from ::std is called. So for debugging purposes i create another specialization for QObject and this one is called:

in my util.h i have:

```
namespace std {
    // QQmlComponent often theses objects
    // are owned by another thread despite their QQmlEngine::CppOwnership, using delete operator
    // directly generate crashes, specify a default_delete specifically for QQmlComponent to
    // use a deleteLater() call over a raw delete

    template<>
    struct  default_delete<QQmlComponent> {
        void operator()(QQmlComponent* ptr) {
            if ( ptr &&
                 QQmlEngine::objectOwnership(ptr) == QQmlEngine::CppOwnership )
                ptr->deleteLater();
        }
    };


    template<>
    struct  default_delete<QObject> {
        void operator()(QObject* ptr) {
           ///...
    };


   }
```

in my utils.cpp i have:

```
std::unique_ptr<QObject> testQObject= std::make_unique<QObject>(new QObject());

std::unique_ptr<QQmlComponent> connectorComponent = std::make_unique<QQmlComponent>(engine, QStringLiteral("qrc:/QuickQanava/VisualConnector.qml"));
```

in `testQObject` the specialized `default_delete` is called and not in `connectorComponent`

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong.
As side note, this code is implemented in a shared library

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your `default_delete` specialisation isn't being called but I can offer you an alternative - you can supply a [custom deleter](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/29/custom-deleters/) to `std::unique_ptr` instead and solve your problem that way.

You do it like this (you don't have to use a lambda if you can't or don't want to):

```
using SmartComponentPtr = std::unique_ptr <QQmlComponent, void (*) (QQmlComponent *)>;

inline SmartComponentPtr MakeSmartComponentPtr (QQmlComponent *component)
{
    return SmartComponentPtr (component, [] (auto component) { /* do funky stuff to delete component here */ } );
};

QQmlComponent *MyComponentPointer = ...
SmartComponentPtr smart_component_pointer = MakeSmartComponentPtr (MyComponentPointer);
// ...
```

A `shared_ptr` can also have a custom deleter, although this costs more.

I created a simple live demo at [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2IioGyqOuUYvGt1V), which also includes the non-lambda version as comments.